# No route matches [GET] for put request to custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I have a users model and controller. I am trying to make a put and delete request to my controller where the put request is tied to users#allow and the delete request is suppose to be directed to users#destroy. I However keep on getting this error when I make the request:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/1/allow"
```

I am also using devise for users and admin classes so that might have something to do with this error. Im not really sure. Here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'users/index'
  put 'users/:id/allow', :to => 'users#allow', :as=>:users_allow
  delete 'users/:id/destroy', :to => 'users#destroy',:as => :users_destroy

  devise_for :users
  devise_for :admins

  root 'website#show'
  resources :tweets do
     put '/pass', :to => 'tweets#pass',:as => :pass
     put '/fail', :to => 'tweets#fail',:as => :fail
  end

  get '/to_json', :to=>'tweets#to_json'
```

end

Here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_user, only:[:allow,:destroy]
   before_filter :authenticate_admin!

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def allow

    find_user.update(:edit_permission=>true)
    redirect_to(:back)
  end

  def destroy
    find_user.destroy
    redirect_to(:back)
  end


  private

    def find_user
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
end
```

And here is my users view where I am calling from, users/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Users#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/index.html.erb</p>
<ul>
    <% @users.each do |user|%>


        <% if user.edit_permission == nil%>
             <li style="color:red"> <%=link_to 'approve', users_allow_path(user), method: :put  %> <%=link_to 'delete', users_destroy_path(user), method: :delete %><%= "#{user.name} #{user.email}"%> </li>
        <% else%>
            <li style="color:green"><%=link_to 'delete', users_destroy_path(user), method: :delete %><%= "#{user.name} #{user.email}"%> </li>
        <% end%>

    <%end%>
</ul>
```

I also want to add that when I go into the view and I do an inspect element in my browser for the link for the put request I do see this:

```
 <a rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/users/1/allow">approve</a>
```

Comment: Does the `allow` method in your controller get executed (i.e. is the record updated in the database) or not at all? Or alternatively, in the logfile, do you see the PUT action being handled before the erroneous GET action, or does the GET action get called in place of the PUT action? I'm thinking it might be your `redirect_to(:back)` playing tricks on you.

Comment: Make sure you have JavaScript enabled in your app else the request will fall back to using `GET`

Comment: it sounds like `jquery_ujs` is not loaded

Comment: Pavan's comment sounds about right. Rails relies on unobstrusive JS to handle the `data-method` attribute. Failing to do that, all links will degrade to GETs.

Answer (score 0):

I would run `rake routes` to see your actual routes, because in your `routes.rb` you actually don't have a route that matches a `get` with `users/:id/allow`

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: [:index, :destroy] do
   put :allow, action: :allow #-> url.com/users/:user_id/allow
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController

   def index
      @users = User.all
   end

   def allow
      user.update edit_permission: true
      redirect_to :back
   end

   private

   def user
      User.find params[:user_id] #-> why return an instance var if you aren't going to use it
   end
end


#app/views/users/index.html.erb
<ul>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <% options = {} %>
        <% options.allow   = ["allow", "red", "put"] %>
        <% options.destroy = ["destroy", "green", "delete"] %>

        <% option = user.edit_permission ? options.allow : [options.allow, options.destroy] %>
        <% option.each do |action,colour,method| %>
            <%= link_to action, eval("users_#{action}_path(user)"), method: method, class: colour %><%= "#{user.name} #{user.email}") %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

--

To fix your actual problem, you need to make sure you have your `Rails UJS` driver loaded:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```